# Volume of a paracompact manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, general-relativity

It is stated, without proof, in Wald (1984) (General Relativity) that given any connected manifold $M$ (which is by definition paracompact), one may define a volume measure $\mu$ such that $\mu[M]$ is finite. Wald stresses the fact that manifolds are paracompact and thus this is possible. This makes me think it has something to do with a partition of unity.

This is my naive guess at how to approach this. Select on $M$ a countable atlas $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$. (Note that $\phi_\alpha:U_\alpha\longrightarrow O_\alpha\subset \mathbb{R}^4$. Perhaps the manifold being 4-dimensional plays a role.) I can measure the hypervolume of each $O_\alpha$ by defining 
$$\mu_E(O_\alpha)=\int_{O_\alpha}\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{R}^4)$$ 
where $\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is the volume form on 4-dimensional Euclidean space and $E$ stands of course for Euclidean. Then perhaps I use the partition of unity to sum these up. I'm not sure how to sum them really or how to make the sum finite. Also how do I define $\mu$ such that I can also act upon a subset $D\subset M$ and find the "volume" of $D$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is false if the manifold is not assumed to be, in addition, connected. What you really want is 2nd countability axiom. As an example, consider an uncountable disjoint union of circles.

Comment: In the case of general relativity, manifolds are generally considered to be connected I believe.

Comment: @0celo7 Yes, but that's a **very** specific subset of all manifolds, even of all $4$-manifolds, and it should be said, especially since we're not physicists, we're mathematicians, and we have no clue what the physics conventions are.

Comment: Sorry, it's just one of those things that is taken for granted in physics texts. Just like we almost always assume the connection is Levi-Civita.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume, as you said in the comment, that $M$ is also connected (it suffices to work with manifolds which have at most countably many components). Then one proves:

**Lemma.** A paracompact connected smooth $n$-dimensional manifold admits a countable, locally finite open cover $\{U_j: j\in J\}$ by open subsets whose closures are diffeomorphic to the closed unit ball $B^n$ in $R^n$. (Countable here refers to the fact that $J$ is contained in the set of natural numbers.)

The proof is not hard, but does take some effort. I will assume the lemma since the solution is already quite long.

I will also assume that $M$ is oriented, otherwise, I have to digress into densities. Choice of orientation will give me a collection of maps $f_j$ for which transition maps are orientation-preserving. Given a cover as above, one proceeds as follows. Let $\{\eta_j: j\in J\}$ be a partition of unity corresponding to this cover and let $f_j: cl(U_j)\to cl(B^n)$ be diffeomorphisms. Then for $B^n$ we take a bump-function $b: B^n\to (0,\infty)$, such that the extension
$$
\tilde{b}= \begin{cases} b(x), & x\in B^n\\
0, & x\in R^n - B^n
\end{cases}
$$
is smooth. By rescaling we can assume that 
$$
\int_{B^n} b =1. 
$$
 Now, let $\omega$ be the standard volume form on $R^n$ and let $\omega_j:= f_j^*(b_j \omega)$. We extend this form by $0$ to the rest of $M$, and retain the notation $\omega_j$ for the extension. For each $j$ we define its $j$-volume:
$$
a_j=\int_{B_j} \omega_j. 
$$
One is now tempted to define the volume density on $M$ as the infinite sum:
$$
\sum_{j\in J} \eta_j \omega_j. 
$$
Such a form would indeed work as a smooth volume form (positivity follows from the fact that compositions $f_i\circ f_j^{-1}$ are orientation-preserving), but its integral over $M$ is, in general, infinite. However, 
$$
\int_{B_j} \eta_j \omega_j \le Vol(B^n). 
$$
Therefore, I will use the density 
$$
\omega= \sum_{j\in J} \frac{1}{j^2} \eta_j \omega_j
$$
and obtain
$$
\int_M \omega \le \sum_{j\in J}  \frac{1}{j^2} <\infty. 
$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrase "extends by $0$". Does this mean we take the support to lie entirely in the chart?

Comment: @0celo7: The extension by $0$ means that you define a function which is $0$ outside of $B^n$ and equal to $b$ in $B^n$. And yes, the support is exactly the unit ball.

Comment: @studiosus: +1, nice one.  But I worry about this: when you pull back the forms, if $M$ is not orientable there may be some sign troubles. In fact, it's not even clear what a volume measure is and what is the total volume, if $M$ is not orientable. Maybe we should work with densities? Just wondering.

Comment: @orangeskid: Yes, of course, you need orientation, otherwise, one has to work with densities.

Comment: @studiosus: Ah, OK, let's just assume it's orientable. Is the form you get everywhere nonzero?

Comment: How does the last inequality come about? Don't you need a partition of unity in there somewhere?

Comment: @0celo7: Yes, I forgot the $\eta_j$ factor in the definition of $\omega$, corrected now. The inequality itself comes from the fact that $\int_M \eta_j \omega_j \le \int_{B^n} b_j \omega=1$

Comment: +1 for dirty physics peasants. Very nice proof. However, I have been doing some digging on the subject and found something. From Hawking & Ellis (1973): To show that the converse is true we introduce a volume measure $\mu$ on $M$ such that the total volume of $M$ is one. One way of doing this is as follows: choose a countable atlas $(U_a,\phi_a)$ for $M$ such that $cl(\phi_a(U_a))$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Let $\mu_0$ be the volume form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and let $f_a$ be a PoU for the atlas. Then $\mu=\sum_a f_a 2^{-a}[\mu_0(U_a)]^{-1}\phi^*_a\mu_0$ has the required properties.

Comment: I can sorta see how this is finite, but I don't know where to start to prove this is equal to one. Also what does $\mu_0(U_a)$ mean?

Comment: @0celo7: Their construction works except it is not smooth (this is why I used the bump-function); otherwise, it is essentially the same what I wrote, except they use the the convergent series $\sum_i 2^{-i}$ and I was using $\sum_i \frac{1}{i^2}$ (which is why the volume is finite). Their $\mu_0$ is the measure obtained by pull-back of the Lebesgue measure on the n-space.

Comment: So what does $\mu_0(U_a)$ mean? I don't see why a 4-form would be acting on an open set. Perhaps it means restriction?

Comment: @0celo7: Instead of $\mu_0(U_a)$ it should be $\int_{R^n} \mu_0$, same as $\int_M \phi_a^*\mu_0$.

Comment: Wait, I thought $\mu$ was a form to be integrated over...so why are there integrals in its definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20285/discussion-between-studiosus-and-0celo7).

Comment: @0celo7: This is an abuse of notation, conflating the volume form and the measure that it defines. If I were them, I would not do this. Them, being Hawking and Ellis.