# Partition of unity for calculating the volume of a paracompact manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, general-relativity

Looking at this question/answers:

[Volume of a paracompact manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105784/volume-of-a-paracompact-manifold)

it is used a partition of unity $\{\eta_j : j \in J\}$ corresponding to the coutable, locally finite open cover $\{ U_j : j \in J\}$, where $J$ is a countable set, to find a finite volume for a paracompact connected manifold $M$. At some point it is said that the following integral
$$
\int_M \sum_{j\in J} \eta_j \omega_j  \tag{1}
$$
can be infinite even though the integral of each term in the sum is finite,
$$
\int_{B_j} \eta_j \omega_j \leq Vol(B^n) , \tag{2}
$$
with $B^n$ the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Then, some $j$-dependent coefficients are introduced in $(1)$ to make the series convergent. What I don't understand is why do we need these coefficients? I mean, by the properties of the partition of unity, all but a finite number of the functions $\eta_j$ are zero in every open set of the cover, which is also locally finite, so the sum in $(1)$ contains actually a finite number of terms and it should be thus finite provided that $(2)$ is satisfied, isn't it?

Comment: Unless $M$ is covered by finitely many of these open sets, I do not follow your reasoning that the sum in (1) is a finite sum.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong then. What I mean is that if at each point of the open set $U_i$ only a finite number of the functions $\eta_j$ are different from zero, then, the sum in (1) is a finite sum. For instance, let's say that there are only $n_i$ functions of the whole set $\{n_j : j \in J \}$ that are different from zero in $U_i$. Then, the sum in $(1)$ is the sum of $n_i$ (finite) elements, isn't it?

Comment: However, what I'm now realizing from your comment is that even though, the integral in $M$ is the sum of the integrals in each $U_j$ of the cover so even in the case that the sum in the integrand is finite we have an infinite number of integrals, i.e.  $\int_M = \sum_i \int_{U_i}\sum_j \eta_j \omega_j$, is that where I was wrong? Could then one say that if the space would be compact, then, because there is a finite cover, the integral would be finite?

Comment: Well, actually, it would not be $\int_M = \sum_i \int_{U_i}$ but rather, $\int_M = \sum_i \int_{V_i}$, where $V_i = U_i - \sum_{j < i} ( U_i \cap U_j)$, but it does not interfere with the reasoning I made, I think